# duplicate-finder-maven-plugin:1.2.1:check -> Found duplicate classes/resources after adding Hibernate Dependency

Tags: java, hibernate, maven, duplicates, dependencies

Trying to build my Maven Project after adding the following the Hibernate Core dependency results in the following warnings and error (1)

```
 [INFO] Checking test classpath
    [WARNING] Found duplicate and different classes in [javax.annotation:javax.annotation-api:1.2, javax.annotation:jsr250-api:1.0]:
    [WARNING]   javax.annotation.Generated
    [WARNING]   javax.annotation.PostConstruct
    [WARNING]   javax.annotation.PreDestroy
    [WARNING]   javax.annotation.Resource
    [WARNING]   javax.annotation.Resources
    [WARNING]   javax.annotation.security.DeclareRoles
    [WARNING]   javax.annotation.security.DenyAll
    [WARNING]   javax.annotation.security.PermitAll
    [WARNING]   javax.annotation.security.RolesAllowed
    [WARNING]   javax.annotation.security.RunAs

    [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.basepom.maven:duplicate-finder-maven-plugin:1.2.1:check (default) on project school.server: Found duplicate classes/resources! -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.basepom.maven:duplicate-finder-maven-plugin:1.2.1:check (default) on project school.server: Found duplicate classes/resources!
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:154)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:146)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:290)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:194)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Found duplicate classes/resources!
    at org.basepom.mojo.duplicatefinder.DuplicateFinderMojo.execute(DuplicateFinderMojo.java:424)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    ... 20 more
```

This is the dependency that must be causing the issue:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
  <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
  <version>5.2.1.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

I tried to work with dependency exclusions on the `javax.annotation` sub-dependency (which classes are duplicated for example), which is not working.

Thank you so much for your help.

Cheers!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `mvn dependency:tree` to figure out all the positions the relevant jars come in. Make sure you excluded them at all those positions.